# SSL configuration with Google AppEngine - redirecting naked domain makes Google Apps bug

Tags: google-app-engine, redirect, ssl, google-apps

I have created an app on AppEngine, and setup my custom domain name on Google Apps. Both the naked domain[enter link description here](https://support.google.com/a/answer/2518373) name and www subdomain work well.

The issues start when I want to setup SSL.

I have a certificate for the domain: `www.mydomain.com`, and the setup worked well in Google Apps. I also configured my app.yaml to `secure: always`, so all requests to http://www.mydomain.com go to https://www.mydomain.com, and all is well.

While all this is working, a request to the naked domain: http://mydomain.com redirects to https://mydomain.com, and fails because Google doesn't support SSL certificates on naked domains (also because I issued my certificate only for www.mydomain.com)

So now I want to redirect my naked domain http://mydomain.com to http://www.mydomain.com, and it should all work like magic.
To do this, I follow [the instructions here](https://developers.google.com/appengine/kb/general?hl=en#naked_domain), which links to this page: ['Enable your "naked" domain address'](https://developers.google.com/appengine/kb/general?hl=en#naked_domain).

But following those simple instructions, here is the error I get (see screenshots):
[image]
[image]
[image]

Any idea how to make the naked domain redirect to the www subdomain?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like wwwizer.com does the trick.

I just created a simple A record pointing to wwwizer's IP in the DNS entries of my domain manager, and it's working. For free.

http(s)://mydomain.com now redirects properly to https://www.mydomain.com

Hopefully AppEngine will add native support for this at some point...