# Google Apps / App Engine: https version of naked domain does not redirect

Tags: google-app-engine, redirect, https, google-apps

I have the following scenario:

- Website is hosted in AppEngine and we want to force it to always load in https. (we use secure:always in app.yaml)
- Domain is managed in Google Apps. We have uploaded SNI certificate and all looks good
- In Google Apps we set the redirect of the naked domain to the www version of it

The following URLs all work:

- http:// website.com (redirects to https:// www.website.com)
- http:// www.website.com (redirects to https:// www.website.com)
- https:// www.website.com (the URL of the app)

However this URL does not redirect and gives an error:

- https:// website.com

Is this a bug or is this a settings issue?

Answer (score 5):

As it is right now, SSL for naked domains does not work directly and this is an expected behavior. This is being tracked as [issue 10802](https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=10802). Also, have a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26357108/app-engine-naked-domain-redirect-ssl), where they found a workaround to use Naked domains and SSL through Google Apps. An alternative solution is proposed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24622339/ssl-configuration-with-google-appengine-redirecting-naked-domain-makes-google).